# Get the commits associated with an Azure DevOps release based on previous release

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When working in Azure DevOps, specifically the release pipelines, you have this nice window on a stage showing the commits that are in this specific release.

[image: Commit history in Azure DevOps for a specific release.]

I would like to use this information within my pipeline, so I can log the commits that went into the specific release and publish them to a different location.

There is the `BUILD_SOURCEVERSION` variable available, but that's the hash from the latest commit.

I've tried using the Azure DevOps REST API and did a GET to `https://vsrm.{{instance}}/{{teamproject}}/_apis/release/releases/{{releaseId}}?api-version=4.1-preview.6`, but I don't think there's any information in there I can use.
I don't think the Pipelines- and Build endpoints provide any useful information for this either. But I could be wrong.

There's the changes endpoint, that can be invoked `https://vsrm.{{instance}}/{{teamproject}}//_apis/Release/releases/{{releaseId}}/changes?baseReleaseId={{previousReleaseId}`. This one works great, but I still need the `previousReleaseId` for this, and more specific the last release id the stage ran on.

Anyone got ideas on how to get the list of commits for a release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rest api [Releases - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) (with release `defintionid`) to get the previous release id in target release.

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?definitionId={definitionId}&api-version=7.1-preview.8
```

PowerShell script sample below:

```
Param(
   [string]$orgnurl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/ORGNAME",
   [string]$projectName = "PROJECTNAME",
   [string]$DefinitionId = "1", #Release definition ID
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "PAT"
)

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

# to get the previous release id:

$getreleaseuri = "$orgnurl/$projectName/_apis/release/releases?definitionId=$DefinitionId" + "&api-version=7.1-preview.8"

$releases = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $getreleaseuri -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$currentreleaseid = $releases.value[0].id

$previousreleaseid = $releases.value[1].id

Write-Host $previousreleaseid $currentreleaseid # check previous release id and current release id

# get changes assosiated with the current release

$uri = "$orgnurl/$projectName/_apis/release/releases/$currentreleaseid/changes?baseReleaseId=$previousreleaseid"

Write-Host $uri  # check uri to get the changes

$commits = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

foreach ($commit in $commits.value.id) {
    Write-Host $commit
}
```

[image]

In addition, if you would like to know the previous release id for specific release(not current release), you can change the code with below(define `$targetrelease` in script as above):

```
$releases = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $getreleaseuri -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$PreviousReleaseId = ($releases.value | Where-Object { $_.id -lt $targetrelease } | Select-Object -First 1).id

echo $PreviousReleaseId
```

Comment: Hi @Jan_V, may i know if there's any update? The script above is working on my side. Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Sorry for responding so late to your answer. This is indeed what I ended up doing, and is working properly. I did discover when a Git artifact is added to the release pipeline, the `changes` endpoint doesn't work anymore. I'm now fetching the details of the current & previous successful run, retrieve the `sourceVersion` from the artifact and do a `git log` between the versions.

Comment: Glad to know it helps! Cheers!